# Customized JAXB xml output

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Given the following class:

```
public class Customer {
  public String name;
  public String lastName;
}
```

I want to generate the following xml output using JAXB for a customer whose `name` is John and `lastName` is Doe:

```
<cst>John Doe</cst>
```

How can i do this with JAXB?

***EDIT***

The class `Customer` is used in several places, as shown here:

```
public class Sale {
  private String productId;
  private Date date;
  private Customer customer;
}

public class Transaction {
  private List<Sale> sales;
}
```

... and so on... The deal is, how can I tell JAXB: "whenever you see a customer, please use custom formatting"?

My problem is that there are many classes that contain a customer, and I want to programatically control the output (sometimes `name + lastname`, sometimes `<name>name</name>`, `<lastname>lastname</lastname>`) without adding annotations at every class that contains `Customer`. This requirement would rule out using `JAXBElement<Customer>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install an `XmlAdapter` that handles the translation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JAXBContext ctxt = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomerWrapper.class);
    Marshaller m = ctxt.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

    Customer customer = new Customer("John", "Doe");
    m.marshal(new JAXBElement<CustomerWrapper>(new QName("cwrapper"), CustomerWrapper.class, new CustomerWrapper(customer)), System.err);

}

static class CustomerWrapper {
    private Customer customer;

    public CustomerWrapper() {
    }

    public CustomerWrapper(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomerAdapter.class)
static class Customer {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    public Customer() {
    }
    public Customer(String name, String lastName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

static class CustomerAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Customer> {

    @Override
    public Customer unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        String[] ss = v.split(" ");
        return new Customer(ss[0], ss[1]);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Customer v) throws Exception {
        return v.getName() + " " + v.getLastName();
    }

}
```

outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cwrapper>
    <customer>John Doe</customer>
</cwrapper>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is getting me closer to my goal... would you be kind enough to see my edit? i oversimplified my original question. thanks!

Comment: This is a strange requirement. You could create subclasses of `Customer` for every type of marshalling and provide an `XmlAdapter` for each but I don't know if this works.

Comment: turns out that your solution works out of the box... using @XmlAdapter makes the magic happen.